# ¿Qué hacer con respuestas que no contestan a la pregunta?

Tags: discusión

En la cola de revisión me he encontrado [esta revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11627) sobre publicaciones de baja calidad (ese link es sólo para los que puedan acceder a la cola, podéis ver la publicación original [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17725/7242))

He seleccionado omitir ya que no sabía seguro cómo tenía que actuar pero me surgen varias dudas.

Si una respuesta tiene buena calidad (no es el caso de la que comparto) pero **no** responde a la pregunta del autor, ¿Cómo debemos actuar? Realmente des de esta cola de revisión ¿deberíamos proponer eliminación sin comentario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las respuestas deben apuntar a resolver la pregunta. Si una respuesta, por más contenido apropiado que tenga, no atiende la respuesta, entonces **no es una buena respuesta**. Imagina uno de los sigueintes escenarios:

1. Una pregunta sobre un problema al implementar una cola en C++ y recibe una respuesta magistral sobre la causa del problema y cómo resolverlo **en Python**.
2. Una pregunta sobre cómo implementar reglas y políticas de ruteo en Apache y recibe una respuesta magnífica sobre **cómo implementar Alta Disponibilidad utilizando Nginx**.
3. Una pregunta respecto a dificultades al crear un algoritmo genético y se publica una respuesta que explica el funcionamiento de las neuronas, cómo esto se utiliza en la programación de redes neuronales y la aplicabilidad de estos temas en el mundo de los negocios junto con una introducción breve a la ciencia de datos (data science). Interesante, pero no se toca para nada el problema particular al implementar este algoritmo genético.

Lo que yo optaría hacer en cada caso:

1. Colocar un comentario en la respuesta indicando que la solución debería considerar C++ en lugar de Python. Si el usuario no hace nada al respecto o responde de manera ofensiva bajo el patrón "yo conozco Python y no C++, así que ese no es mi problema" entonces reportar la publicación.
2. Similar a 1, colocar un comentario para indicar que la pregunta trata sobre Apache, no sobre Nginx y que por favor brinde alguna manera de resolver lo mismo con la otra tecnonlogía. En este caso, por lo menos brindar enlaces a donde se pueda cubrir el problema puntual. Solo reportaría la respuesta si el usuario sigue el mismo patrón explicado en 1.
3. Colocaría un comentario indicando que el conocimiento compartido es bueno pero que necesita atender a la pregunta. El conocimiento es bienvenido, pero para publicar esa información puede utilizar un blog y luego compartirlo mediante sus redes sociales, quizás en la sala de chat, entre otros. Esta respuesta sí la reportaría de inmediato puesto que, para los estándares del sitio, lastimosamente solo es ruido por no responder a la pregunta en ningún momento.

Comment: Si nos encontramos estos casos en la cola de revisión, ¿proponemos eliminación sin comentario? ¡Gracias por la contestación!

Comment: En los casos 1 y 2 no propongo que se elimine porque hay información rescatable que puede aplicar a resolver el problema pero otra parte está fuera de eso por lo que considero notificar al usuario para que corrija eso o que pida ayuda a alguien que sepa al respecto y edite su eespuesta. En el caso 3, sí considero que se deba elilinar porque de ninguna forma responde a la pregunta.